# I would like to combine output of below script in one text file

Tags: powershell

```
Write-Host "Drive information for $env:ComputerName"

Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk |
    Where-Object {$_.DriveType -ne 5} |
    Sort-Object -Property Name | 
    Select-Object Name, VolumeName, VolumeSerialNumber,SerialNumber, FileSystem, Description, VolumeDirty, `
        @{"Label"="DiskSize(GB)";"Expression"={"{0:N}" -f ($_.Size/1GB) -as [float]}}, `
        @{"Label"="FreeSpace(GB)";"Expression"={"{0:N}" -f ($_.FreeSpace/1GB) -as [float]}}, `
        @{"Label"="%Free";"Expression"={"{0:N}" -f ($_.FreeSpace/$_.Size*100) -as [float]}} |
    Format-Table -AutoSize
```

---

```
gcim Win32_OperatingSystem | f1 * | f1 > info.txt; notepad.exe info.txt
```

Comment: Use the "append" redirection operator (`>>`), `Add-Content`, or the `-Append` parameter of an appropriate output cmdlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  $path="$([Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop"))\info.txt"; 
  gcim Win32_OperatingSystem | select Caption, InstallDate | fl | out-file  $path; 
  "Drive information for $env:ComputerName" | out-file  $path -Append;  
  Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk | Where-Object {$_.DriveType -ne 5} | Sort-Object -Property Name | Select-Object Name, VolumeName, VolumeSerialNumber,SerialNumber, FileSystem, Description, VolumeDirty, ` @{"Label"="DiskSize(GB)";"Expression"={"{0:N}" -f ($_.Size/1GB) -as [float]}}, ` @{"Label"="FreeSpace(GB)";"Expression"={"{0:N}" -f ($_.FreeSpace/1GB) -as [float]}}, ` @{"Label"="%Free";"Expression"={"{0:N}" -f ($_.FreeSpace/$_.Size*100) -as [float]}} | Format-Table -AutoSize | out-file $path -Append

  notepad $path;
```

Comment: I have to combine ouput of two script in one text file:

Comment: $path="$([Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop"))\info.txt"; gcim Win32_OperatingSystem | select Caption, InstallDate | fl > $path; notepad $path;

Comment: Write-Host "Drive information for $env:ComputerName"

Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk |
    Where-Object {$_.DriveType -ne 5} |
    Sort-Object -Property Name | 
    Select-Object Name, VolumeName, VolumeSerialNumber,SerialNumber, FileSystem, Description, VolumeDirty, `
        @{"Label"="DiskSize(GB)";"Expression"={"{0:N}" -f ($_.Size/1GB) -as [float]}}, `
        @{"Label"="FreeSpace(GB)";"Expression"={"{0:N}" -f ($_.FreeSpace/1GB) -as [float]}}, `
        @{"Label"="%Free";"Expression"={"{0:N}" -f ($_.FreeSpace/$_.Size*100) -as [float]}} |
    Format-Table -AutoSize

Comment: the above two scripts should produce result in info.txt, which is stored at desktop location

Comment: Thanks, In the same script can we add to check if firewall is enabled or not, wat is machine description, is remote connections allowed?

Comment: Of course. Add PowerShell command before this : | out-file $path -append

Comment: pls help me in this new qstn..

if ($combobox1.SelectedItem.ToString == "Computer name")
 {
  $path = "$([Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop"))\information.txt";
  gcim Win32_OperatingSystem | fL * | fl > $path; notepad $path;
 }